# How do you digitally sign a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage?

Tags: .net-3.5, system.net.mail

One of the requirements of the project I am working at involves digitally signing e-mail messages. I can, of course, build the messages and send them through a `SMTPClient`, but I really can't figure out how to digitally sign them. I have some `.pfx` files whose path and password I must provide to the constructor of the `X509Certificate2` class, but from this point onwards I am completely clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before sending the message you could sign it with your algorithm depending on what is the method for that

//Pseudo Code

```
message.Sign(SignerAlgo)

Smtp.Send(message);
```

Here is an example using pfx file

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/74e4711e-1f66-43a7-9e3b-bc9cfbcd1b73/

which involves

1. Loading a cert from PFX file
2. Signing the message
3. Generating signed envelope

Comment: Are you really sure this works? There is no `Sign` method in the `MailMessage` class.

Comment: Yes that is just a pseudo code to  tell you how this could work, but try the example in the link provided and you should be able to work this out.